# YAML / SnakeYAML: how refer to the same object multiple times

Tags: java, yaml

I am using YAML to import data into a db4o database and am wondering how I can structure my documents such that when I create an object, I can re-use that same object later on in another object.  For instance, I declare a content type, and then a file after it that uses that content type.

How do I refer to that content type?

Walter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using YAML you may represent objects of arbitrary graph-like structures. If you want to refer to the same object from different parts of a document, you need to use anchors and aliases

http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Aliases

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will have to try that out.